# Remove Exim version number

Tags: exim, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to get rid of the version number that you see when you get an email sent from Exim.

```
Received: from user1 by site.org with local (Exim 4.72)
```

I'v tried editing smtp_banner in these two files

```
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template
```

But deleting the version number from there, then reloading Exim's config doesn't work.

I send my test emails like so:

```
echo "Message Content" | mail -s "Subject goes here" email@email.com -v
```

**Update 1**

```
comp1:/etc/exim4# ls -l /etc/exim4/
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root         4096 Jul 30  2010 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        76239 Jan 21 08:24 exim4.conf.template
-rw-r----- 1 root Debian-exim   204 Sep 30  2008 passwd.client
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         1462 Jan 21 07:39 update-exim4.conf.conf
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/exim.conf` and find the key `smtp_banner`, then change that line in this way :

**From**

```
smtp_banner = "${primary_hostname} ESMTP Exim ${version_number} \
```

**To**

```
smtp_banner = "${primary_hostname} ESMTP \
```

Comment: I don't have a exim.conf file, Debian uses splt config. ls: cannot access /etc/exim.conf: No such file or directory. Check out update one on my org post.

Comment: `grep version_number -R /etc` and find where it's located then

Comment: Use `grep -r smtp_banner /etc/exim/` to find the correct file.

Comment: first one comes up with `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options:` I'v changed this deleted the version number + restart but it still shows when sending an email. The 2nd one comes up with the two files listed in my org post, which I have already changed and it had no effect.

Comment: It is strange there is something wrong in the setup ... The file /etc/exim.conf should exist in a standard setup ... How have you installed Exim ?

Comment: I don't recall installing it, pretty sure it came pre-installed. But if I did, it would of been `apt-get install exim4`. From what I'v read it seems Debian is a bit different then other *nix distros when it comes to exim's config, which makes it rather hard to get conventional help from the internet.

Comment: Did you run `update-exim4.conf` after you changed the config file?

Comment: Yes, but it still shows up in emails.

Answer (score 4):

smtp_banner modifies the banner displayed to the client upon connection, but it looks like you want to change what's being put in the Received: header.

For that, you'll want to define received_header_text, probably in /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options.  The option isn't in the file by default, but per the [documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html) the default setting is

```
received_header_text = Received: \
  ${if def:sender_rcvhost {from $sender_rcvhost\n\t}\
  {${if def:sender_ident \
  {from ${quote_local_part:$sender_ident} }}\
  ${if def:sender_helo_name {(helo=$sender_helo_name)\n\t}}}}\
  by $primary_hostname \
  ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} \
  ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}\
  (Exim $version_number)\n\t\
  ${if def:sender_address \
  {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}\
  id $message_exim_id\
  ${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}
```

So you should be able to just paste the above text into your config, making whatever changes you'd like.

Comment: I also tried that. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:

```
$ grep  smtp_banner /etc/exim4/*
/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:# smtp_banner = $smtp_active_hostname ESMTP Exim $version_number $tod_full
```

There do what aleroot suggested.

Comment: I'v tried that, it doesn't make any difference. I even done a system restart.

Comment: did you ran update-exim4.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

The post shows the macros that need to be set, but is not clear about how to set them.  If you are using a Debian/Ubuntu system you can define them in 
`/etc/exim4/exim.conf.localmacros`.  If you are using the split configuration, then you should create a symlink to this file with a name like `00_exim-conf-localmacros` in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main`.   Once you have done this you can restart.

Check the configuration in `/var/lib/exim/conf.autogenerated` to ensure your macros are included.

If you are using other systems, the configuration file may be provided using a different mechanism.  The default configuration may be `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf`.  Debian/Ubuntu systems will use this it it exists.

It appears you may need to make a number of configuration changes.  On a Debian/Ubuntu system I would suggest you use the split configuration.  If you make your changes using the documented mechanism, version updates should not break or loose your configuration changes.