# Remove or Hide Exim version

Tags: exim

Have looked around the Internet and at ServerFault the similar question has no solution:

[Remove Exim version number](https://serverfault.com/questions/352176/remove-exim-version-number#new-answer)

Neither `received_header_text` in options `config` or `smtp_banner` is working. Seems a receiver detect Exim version in another way and don't care about my header that I specifying.

Any ideas to change information in Received header for free mailbox providers?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the SMTP version/banner follow the steps below

Open the file /etc/exim.conf and find for smtp_banner.

The line would look like

smtp_banner = "${primary_hostname} ESMTP Exim ${version_number} \
Remove the "Exim ${version_number}" from the line. The modified line would look like

smtp_banner = "${primary_hostname} ESMTP \

Comment: As I said in a topic - it does not work.